# how to configure sitemap.xml in angularjs app

Tags: jquery, angularjs, xml

This sitemap.xml I tried but not working in my angularjs app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84"><url><loc>https://example.co.in/</loc><lastmod>2016-06-10</lastmod><changefreq>Daily</changefreq><priority>1</priority></url><url><loc>https://example.co.in/</loc><lastmod>2016-06-10</lastmod><changefreq>Daily</changefreq><priority>1</priority></url></urlset>
```

In my angular app statename serving a file.

```
.state('sitemap.xml', {url: '/sitemap.xml'})
```

any idea to configure sitemap?